# navigator.geolocation taking upwards of a minute to complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

I am trying to init a certain view in an app based on a user's geolocation using the `navigator.geolocation` api `getUserLocation` func and the timing it takes for the success/fail callbacks to fire is so slow (log shows a timeout init'd when the reducer is initially fired):
[image]

... sometimes EXTREMELY slow:
[image]

I've tried passing both `{ enableHighAccuracy: true` and `false }` as options to the function, and nothing seems to help.

Any way to improve this, wise people of the internet?

(setting a max timeout in opts isn't desirable, we want the user's location if they choose to geolocate themselves)

Also, this is in Chrome, so I imagine it's only gonna be worse in other cases...

Answer (score 0):

What version of Chrome are you on? There seems to be a known issue with Chrome v65. I updated to Chrome v66 and it seems to work consistently again. Although I still can't figure out why it's so slow (takes 5-10 seconds) whereas in safari it's pretty much instant. First time I've seen Safari handle something better than Chrome.

[Here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820945&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=geolocation&colspec=ID&groupby=&sort=) is the link to the issue on chromium.